# Flashing Athom Wall plug ESP8285

Tags: esp8266

I'm trying to re-flash an [Athom](https://www.athom.tech/blank-1/israel-plug) plug (bought pre-flashed with HomeKit firmware) using FTDI adapter.

Shown [here](https://templates.blakadder.com/athom_PG01V2-EU16A-TAS.html) is the exact ESP8285 (different plug sub-model). AFAIK ESP8285 is a similar MCU to ESP8266 regarding pulling down GPIO0 to GND prior to powering the MCU in order enable uploading a new sketch/firmware.

When doing so- it flahing failed.
2 other method that I've tried, failed:

1. This [link](https://templates.blakadder.com/athom_PG01EU16A.html) shows that RST should me pulled down to GND.
2. This [link](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Get-Started-With-ESP8285-Module-/) explains that GPIO0 should be help entire time (from powering until end of flashing).

Answer (score 2):

**The correct procedure is:**

1. Power up your ESP programming setup, and connect it to your PC.
2. Press and hold the Reset button, and then press and hold the Flash
   button (pull GPIO0 low/GND).
3. Release the Reset button and then release the Flash button.
4. Click the START button in the flash download tool GUI window.

**The boot procedure for ESP8266:**

When a ESP8266 starts/or is reset it start to check the GPIO0 status, that decides if it should start the program or get into serial bootloader mode (Flash mode).

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/esp8266/advanced-topics/boot-mode-selection.html#select-bootloader-mode

Comment: what you described is a normal ESP8266 upload (at least the pulling down GPIO0 to GND is familiar).
Beside that, which I did, it failed ( as described in my question). is there something that I did wrong ?